# OpenCV Implement Adobe Photoshops Brightness/Contrast function

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to implement the Brightness/Contrast function like in Adobe Photoshop. Has anyone an idea how to do that?
(A formula or something would be nice ;) )

Comment: Brightness adds a constant, Contrast multiplies by a constant.

Comment: Ok, I tried this and faced the following problem. Adding a value to adjust the contrast might work, but it is not how it's done in Photoshop. I tested an image with grayvalues -> adjusting brightness in Photoshop makes only the light parts brighter / darker and the dark parts stay the same (or it looks like it's the same). Adjusting the brightness in the way you suggested, the dark parts get brighter too. Has anyone a hint, how this is done in Photoshop?

Comment: Apparently Photoshop has 2 ways of adjusting brightness and contrast. The method I described is "Legacy", and I don't know anything about the new method. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WS6F4BFD05-7169-4fda-9003-3751F79CEC70.html#WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-764ea